# How to return to main when timer stopped from other class in c# console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a class with timer like below

```
public class helper
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    private int counter = 0;
    private int returnCode = 0;


    public int Process()
    {
        SetTimer();
        Console.WriteLine("The application started ");
        return counter;

    }

    public void SetTimer()
    {
        int optionalWay = 0;
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => OnTimedEvent(sender, e, optionalWay);         

        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e, int optionalWay)
    {
        counter++;
        Console.WriteLine("Timer is ticking");

        if (counter == 10)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Dispose();
            returnCode = returnCode + 1;
        }
    }       
}
```

I have main function like this below

```
public static void Main()
{
    helper helper = new helper();
    int code = helper.Process();
    Console.WriteLine("Main " + code.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

what I want to do is return to main when my timer is stopped, not before that

, my timer class is running fine, main is getting printed like below

So main should wait till the result from timer is 1. And then end process

Comment: Ok but your timer wont have run by the time of the return so yes, 0 would be correct

Comment: Your edit makes it even less clear what you want. If you want main "to wait" until the result is 1 then you need to all access to the return code from main - at the moment it is private with no public property to access it.

Comment: Check the update of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is working as it should. There is nothing inside the `helper.Process()` function that can wait or block the execution, so the function is returning immediately to the `main` before the `OnTimedEvent` is even executed.

A workaround can be done by implementing an event in the `helper` class and raise that event after the timer completes its work. And the `main` can listen to that event and act accordingly.

```
public class helper
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    private int counter = 0;
    private int returnCode = 0;

    public event EventHandler<int> Done;
    ...

    private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e, int optionalWay)
    {
        counter++;
        Console.WriteLine("Timer is ticking");

        if (counter == 10)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Dispose();
            returnCode = returnCode + 1;

            if (Done != null)
            {
                Done.Invoke(this, returnCode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the `Program.cs`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    helper helper = new helper();
    helper.Done += helper_Done;
    helper.Process();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void helper_Done(object sender, int e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Main " + e.ToString());
}
```

**Update**

The Timer class uses a new thread from *ThreadPool* to execute the `Elapsed` event handler. So it cannot return to the `Main` which is running on a different thread. In short: what you are trying to do cannot not be achieved with a Timer.

Here is another solution using `Thread.Sleep()` which will satisfy your requirement, but keep in mind using `Thread.Sleep()` like this is **not recommended**.

```
public class helper
{
    private int counter = 0;
    private int returnCode = 0;

    public int Process()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The application started ");
        StartTimer(2000);
        return returnCode;
    }

    private void StartTimer(int ms)
    {
        while (counter++ < 10)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ms);
            Console.WriteLine("Timer is ticking");
        }
        returnCode = returnCode + 1;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        helper helper = new helper();
        int code = helper.Process();
        Console.WriteLine("Main " + code.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Again, this is **NOT** a good practice to use `Thread.Sleep` for a delayed execution and `Thread.Sleep` is less accurate compare to `Timer.Elapsed`. Try to change the design of your application and use *Event* or *Callback function*.

Comment: what's the difference between your answer and the one I've provided and you downvoted?

Comment: In case you don't want to add an event, you can add a callback function like 
@FacundoLaRocca suggested in the second example of his answer.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca I don't know who downvoted your answer. In my opinion, your second solution is a good one. Event or callback either will solve the OP's question.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the mistake. I'll vote your answer up then

Comment: @Faruq how to return to the main method but not to the helper_done method. as I have to return the int value to the job which is calling this exe

Comment: @Shaswata I guess you are getting confused about the execution flow of the program. The program is always returning to the main method right after  executing `Console.WriteLine("The application started ");`. I will update my answer later today to add more.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Process` function of `helper` class to accept a callback:

```
public void Process(Action<int> callBack)
{
    SetTimer();
    Console.WriteLine("The application started ");
    if (timer != null)
        timer.Disposed += (o, e) => callBack(counter);
}
```

Change the main function to send the callback:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

    helper helper = new helper();
    helper.Process(c => Console.WriteLine("Main " + c.ToString()));            
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two options in mind, one of them and the ugliest, is to loop until timer is stopped, basically doing so:

```
public class helper
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    private int counter = 0;
    private int returnCode = 0;
    private bool timerWorking = false;

    public int Process()
    {
        SetTimer();
        Console.WriteLine("The application started ");
        while(timerWorking){}
        return counter;
    }

    public void SetTimer()
    {
        // All the staff you already have
        timerWorking = true;
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e, int optionalWay)
    {
        counter++;
        Console.WriteLine("Timer is ticking");

        if (counter == 10)
        {
            //All the staff you already have
            timerWorking = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, the more elegant, passing or registering a callback to be executed once the ending point is reached:

```
public class helper
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    private int counter = 0;
    private int returnCode = 0;
    Action<int> _doAfterTimerEnds


    public void Process(Action<int> doAfterTimerEnds)
    {
        SetTimer();
        _doAfterTimerEnds = doAfterTimerEnds;
        Console.WriteLine("The application started ");
    }

    public void SetTimer()
    {
        int optionalWay = 0;
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => OnTimedEvent(sender, e, optionalWay);         

        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e, int optionalWay)
    {
        counter++;
        Console.WriteLine("Timer is ticking");

        if (counter == 10)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Dispose();
            returnCode = returnCode + 1;
            _doAfterTimerEnds(returnCode)
        }
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var returnCode = 0;
    var helper = new helper();
    helper.Process(code => returnCode = code);

    while (returnCode != 1) {}

    Console.WriteLine("Main " + returnCode);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**UPDATE**: I've tested this last version and it is working as expected.

Comment: the second way does not work . i cant use that first way , as there are multiple values not only true or false.

Comment: second way is not working as directly printing the initial value and not waiting for the timer to be completed